# Changing the dot (.) into comma (,) in Google Sheets, how do I do that? (numerical pad, in Holland, for currency)

Tags: google-sheets, localization

I already managed to change the dot on numerical pad into a comma in i.e.  excel.  But how do I do that in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File > Settings` Then set `Locale` to the Neatherlands.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that finds if the entered value is a text string that looks like `0000.00`, and converts it to a number if that is the case.

See [Replace the decimal mark produced by the numeric keypad with a comma in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69656946/13045193).